# Computing $\text{Ext}^k(\mathbb{F}_p, \mathbb{Z}[t])$ of an exact sequence

Tags: commutative-algebra, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, exact-sequence

The exact sequence is defined as follows:

$$0\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}[t]\xrightarrow{\binom{1-t}{p}}\mathbb{Z}[t]\oplus\mathbb{Z}[t]\xrightarrow{(p, t-1)}\mathbb{Z}[t]\xrightarrow{\eta}\mathbb{F}_p\rightarrow 0$$

These are all $\mathbb{Z}[t]$-modules.
The morphism is defined to be the usual multiplication and $\eta(t)=1$. For example, if $f(t)\in \mathbb{Z}[t]$, then $\binom{1-t}{p}(f(t))=\binom{(1-t)f(t)}{pf(t)}$. If $\binom{f(t)}{g(t)}\in \mathbb{Z}[t]\oplus\mathbb{Z}[t]$, then $(p,t-1)\binom{f(t)}{g(t)}=pf(t)+(t-1)g(t)$.

The goal is to compute $\text{Ext}^k(\mathbb{F}_p, \mathbb{Z}[t])$.
I can't work out the computation details. Could someone give a hint?

Comment: What cohomology are you talking about?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Cohomology of modules. Applying the $Hom(-,\mathbb{Z}[t])$ functor to the above sequence, we have a new sequence of modules of homomorphisms between the above modules and $\mathbb{Z}[t]$. Then it should be enough to compute its cohomology, but I have no idea how to proceed.

Comment: Of modules? Over what ring? Your notation seems very weird for that...

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Sorry I wasn't so clear about this. They are all $\mathbb{Z}$-modules.

Comment: So what you are writing H^k(F_p,Z[t]) is what one usually writes Ext_Z^k(F_p,Z[t])? In that case, Z_p has a much simpler projective resolution as a Z-module, that looks like Z -> Z with the map being multiplication by p.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Right. $H^k(\mathbb{F}_p, \mathbb{Z}[t])$ is what our professor uses in lectures. So I followed his notation. Sorry I didn't explain more.

Comment: I suggest you use standard notation, so that the people that could answer but do not even know what you are talking about only because of your notation can. Edit the question.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Thanks for your suggestion. I edited my question and added more explanations.

Comment: @pcZhang Are you sure you do not want to consider $\mathbb F_p$ as a $\mathbb Z[t]$-module?

Comment: Ah. Thank you! I see where the problem is now. It makes so much sense if it's a $\mathbb{Z}[t]$-module.

Comment: Maybe just double check with your lecture notes or lecturer to be sure...